# PageIndexChanging Event in search button in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, page-index-changed

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    {

        grid();


    }
   } 

  protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        objRetailPL.ZoneName = ddlzone.SelectedValue;


        //IFormatProvider provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA", true);
        //String datetime = txtdate.Text.ToString();
        //DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(datetime, provider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);

        //objRetailPL.date =dt;
        DataTable dtsearch = new DataTable();
        dtsearch = objRetailBAL.searchzone(objRetailPL);
        GVRate.DataSource = dtsearch;
        GVRate.DataBind();



}
   protected void GVRate_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
  {
  try
  {
      GVRate.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
      grid();

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {         

  }
 }
```

I have this code for searching records.And for that grid i added page index,but it is not coming properly.When click on search button it is showing more n of records at that time page index is not working. It is calling First grid before clicking search button..How can I change my code please help me.....

Comment: It is showing gridview with some columns.....like date,rate etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
    private void grid()
   {
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourSearchTextBox.Text)
      {
      // Then call search method. Make sure you bind the Grid in that method.
      }
      else
      {
      // Normally Bind the Grid as you are already doing in this method.
      }
   }
```

you have to check whether there is any search Text or not in that grid() method like...